# How to make profile and post/image/video public or private on the same time i have example

Tags: javascript, php

As we can see our post can be public,private or custom on facebook.
how can we do the same from the php coding?
the changes will be instant like on fb.
please refer me the code or solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    try {
        $('#post-visibility-display').text('<?php echo $visibility_trans; ?>');
        $('#hidden-post-visibility').val('<?php echo $visibility; ?>');
        $('#visibility-radio-<?php echo $visibility; ?>').attr('checked', true);
    } catch(err){}
}) (jQuery);
</script>
```

}

Comment: like we have two radio box one for private and one for public and when we click on public radio box , our profile will be public for all and when we select private our profile will be hidden from everyone.

Comment: same like post if we select public then it will visible to all the users and if we select private then it will be hidden from users.

Comment: That question still doesn’t fit here on SO any better than your [previous one on the same topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298210/how-to-make-profile-and-post-image-video-public-or-private-on-the-same-time). Please go read [ask] first.

Answer (score 0):

there are different ways of implementing this, i would do something like-

first my table will contain 3 columns user_id, post, visibility_status. the visibility_status will be 0 for public,1 for private.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
var post=$("#mytext").html();
var status=("#rad").val();
$.ajax({
here will be your ajax request to insert records......

})

})

})
<script>

<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
public <input type="radio" id="rad"  value="0" checked='true' />
              private  <input type="radio" id="rad"  value="1" />
```

Comment: but the changes will not from the submit button?it will change when we select the radio button.correct??

Comment: @nikita! yes! you can do that, but then your jquery function will be called onchange of radio button, but what if you want to make 2 public posts of after another? will you go on refresh the page? and yes! kindly accept the answer if that fits to your needs.